# Filter out Subnet IDs based on sufficient capacity in availability zones in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm **trying to deploy an EKS cluster** and everything seems to be fine except for one!

The **facade module** looks like this:

```
module "eks" {
  source = "../../../../infrastructure_modules/eks"

  ## EKS ##
  create_eks      = var.create_eks
  cluster_version = var.cluster_version
  cluster_name    = local.cluster_name
  vpc_id          = data.aws_vpc.this.id
  subnets         = data.aws_subnet_ids.this.ids

  # note: either pass worker_groups or node_groups
  # this is for (EKSCTL API) unmanaged node group
  worker_groups = var.worker_groups

  # this is for (EKS API) managed node group
  node_groups = var.node_groups

  ## Common tag metadata ##
  env      = var.env
  app_name = var.app_name
  tags     = local.eks_tags
  region   = var.region
}
```

The **VPC id** is retrieved through the following block :

```
data "aws_vpc" "this" {
  tags = {
    Name = "tagName"
  }
}
```

Which then is used to retrieve the **subnet_IDs** as following:

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "this" {
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.this.id
}
```

Nevertheless, **deploying this results in error** stating:

> Error: error creating EKS Cluster (data-layer-eks):
> UnsupportedAvailabilityZoneException: Cannot create cluster
> 'data-layer-eks' because us-east-1e, the targeted availability zone,
> does not currently have sufficient capacity to support the cluster.

Which is a **well known error**, and anybody can come across this for even EC2s.

I could **solve this by simply hardcoding the subnet value**, but that's really undesirable and hardly maintainable.

So the question is, **how can I filter out subnet_IDs based on availability zones that have sufficient capacity**?

Comment: I would suggest caution about your desired goal here: it's risky to write a Terraform configuration that declares objects that vary based on constantly-changing values such as the capacity of an availability zone, because an availability zone that has insufficient capacity today could have sufficient capacity tomorrow, which would then cause your set of declared availability zones to change even though your configuration did not.

Comment: @MartinAtkins good point, thanks mate.

Comment: I've wondered about this myself.  If a terraform apply is re-run if the list of available AZs changes, would resources potentially get "moved" undesirably?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to collect the subnets with all of their attributes:

```
data "aws_subnets" "this" {
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [data.aws_vpc.this.id]
  }
}

data "aws_subnet" "this" {
  for_each = toset(data.aws_subnets.this.ids)
  id       = each.value
}
```

`data.aws_subnet.this` is now a `map(object)` with all of the subnets and their attributes. You can now filter by availability zone accordingly:

```
subnets = [for subnet in data.aws_subnet.this : subnet.id if subnet.availability_zone != "us-east-1e"]
```

You can also filter by truthy conditionals if that condition is easier for you:

```
subnets = [for subnet in data.aws_subnet.this : subnet.id if contains(["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c", "us-east-1d"], subnet.availability_zone)]
```

It depends on your personal use case.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
data "aws_subnets" "default" {
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [data.aws_vpc.default.id]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "availability-zone-id"
    values = ["use1-az1", "use1-az2", "use1-az4", "use1-az6"]
  }
}
```